# Substituting variables into an implicit equation and then plot it

Tags: plotting, replacement

I tried this:

```
ContourPlot[(4-d^b==0)/.b->1/t, {t,0,1},{d,0,4}]
```

However, nothing is plotted. This works fine instead:

```
ContourPlot[4-d^(1/t)==0, {t,0,1},{d,0,4}]
```

Why is that? How should I use the first code to plot the equation?

Comment: `ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[(4 - d^b == 0) /. b -> 1/t], {t, 0, 1}, {d, 0, 4}]` would work with the same `General` message.

Comment: Alternatively, use `With[{b = 1/t}, ContourPlot[(4 - d^b == 0), {t, 0, 1}, {d, 0, 4}]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at:

```
Attributes[ContourPlot]

{HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}
```

The attribute "HoldAll" prevents the replacement to be executed before calling ContourPlot. To force the execution, use "Evaluate" like:

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[(4 - d^b == 0) /. b -> 1/t], {t, 0, 1}, {d, 0, 4}]
```